# Excel VBA a lot of problems

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm new to VBA, and I am trying to get a macro to compare cells, and output a counter in the column next to it. Here is my code:

```
Sub Duplicate_Count()

'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim value1 As String
Dim value2 As String
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Search down row for duplicates
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To LastRow

    'Sets value1 and value2 to be compared
    value1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
    value2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, "L").Value

    'If values are not diferent then counter will not increment
    If value1 <> value2 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

    'Sets the n colom to count, duplicates should not increment the counter
    Sheet1.Cells(i, "N") = counter

Next i
```

End Sub

Okay so this code runs, and it looks it works, column "N" starts to populate, but the program freezes up, and I do not know if it is just because the file is so large that it takes a lot of time, or if something is wrong. If i restart the program i get run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method '_Default" of object "Range" failed. Any idea what that means?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, hopefully, I'm not just making dumb mistakes.

EDIT:
Sub Duplicate_Count()
    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim value1 As String
Dim value2 As String
Dim counter As Long
counter = 0
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Search down row for duplicates
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To LastRow

    'Sets value1 and value2 to be compared
    value1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
    value2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, "L").Value

    'If values are not diferent then counter will not increment
    If value1 <> value2 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

    'Sets the n colom to count, duplicates should not increment the counter
    sht.Cells(i, "N") = counter

Next i
```

End Sub

This code crashes every time, and will occasionally give me an error of run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method '_Default" of object "Range" failed. I have no idea how to fix that... or what it even means.

Comment: The first potential problem I notice is that you set counter to 1 each time you loop, do you want it to do that? At the same time, you don't _need_ to `Dim` each variable every time you loop

Comment: No i realize that that could be moved out of the loop, thanks!

Comment: You could use a simple =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,A1) perhaps?

Comment: Okay Dexloft so that seems to have fixed it. It is a huge file so it is taking a long time to finish, I will let you know if i have any other issues. Thanks again!

Comment: jkpieterse, that might work, but the file im going to run this in changes length and i prefer to not have to edit the function every file i need to run the macro in. that is if i understand what you posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty this is the code I finished with:

Sub Duplicate_Count()

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim value1 As String
Dim value2 As String
Dim counter As Long
counter = 0
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Find the last used row in Column L
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Search down row for duplicates
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To LastRow - 1


    'Sets value1 and value2 to be compared
    value1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
    value2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, "L").Value

    'If values are not diferent then counter will not increment
    If value1 <> value2 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

    'Sets the n colom to count, duplicates should not increment the counter
    sht.Cells(i + 1, "N") = counter

Next i
```

End Sub

Thank you so much everyone for your help! Turns out that the values are strings because I had some headers being looked at, and setting the worksheet was one of my biggest problems, as to it having the run time error, i believe that is just because the document is so long. I let it sit for 30 min and it completed just fine. 
Thanks again for the help everyone !

Answer (score 0):

I don't get an error when I run your code, but I made some changes I think might fix it. Try this and let me know what happens!

```
 Sub TommysMacro()
    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim counter As Integer

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(65536, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Sets values to be compared
    ReDim cellValue(1 To LastRow) As String
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        cellValue(i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
    Next i

    'Search down row for duplicates
    For i = 1 To LastRow - 1

        'If values are not diferent then counter will not increment
        If cellValue(i) <> cellValue(i + 1) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        'Sets the n column to count, duplicates should not increment the counter
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "N").Value = counter

    Next i

End Sub
```

I just changed it after I saw your comment about it being a large column, I think this should be much faster!

Comment: Yes `Sheet1` is not defined and gives `Object Required` Error. I would also set a variable as worksheet. with `Dim sht as Worksheet` and `Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")`. Now you can use `sht` instead of `Worksheets("Sheet1")` , which makes the code more handy. To even make this shorter you could use a `With sht` for the entire code after the `Dim` Mehtods.

Comment: What is the L65536 for?

Comment: On Excel 2003 and old versions like that, it's the maximum row value possible. Since you got an error and I didn't (I'm using Excel 2007), I figured you might have an older version so I just used that in case. Basically, it goes to the very last row in column L and then uses `.End(xlUp)` from there to get the last used row in L. But I noticed an error in my method, it doesn't do the last row in the column because my loop goes to LastRow - 1

Comment: @UGP, yeah I always see people doing that but I never really liked the way it looked and sometimes I even found it hard to follow, personally. Do you think those are things I should start doing or do you think it's more of a personal preference thing?

Comment: On a short code like this, it not really necessary to use a `with` but i would definitly use a variable for the worksheet. It helps, if you need to adjust anything and writing a lot easier and short. I would recommend using it every time.

Comment: So i got the code running i believe, but it crashes every time:run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method '_Default" of object "Range" failed. Any idea what that means?

Comment: @UGP Ok, I'll for sure start trying to use it. I definitely agree that it would be easier to make changes, and anything that would confuse me is just bad variable naming on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I just like triple checked everything and I have no clue where that error could come from. Did you change anything? Also 2 questions, what version of excel are you using and do you know how to step through code?

Comment: I made another edit to the code, this works for the last row and hopefully gets rid of that error even though I don't know which part could be giving it to you

Comment: The code looks the same as the second block on the original question, and i am running excel 2013. I am currently stepping through the code, the problem is that it will run until the counter reaches around 734 then crashes, so stepping that far takes some time

Comment: Well that is definitely really random then, try to make the for loop condition be `For i = 1 to 733` and see if that works just fine. Then, try `For i = 734 To LastRow - 1` and that'll be easier to step through. Is there something weird about row 734?

Comment: So i just set the for loop to go to row 1000 and it worked fine, so im wondering if the problem is that it takes a while, as it is usually going through to 114,623. So im going to just let it run, and see if in a couple of minutes it has finished.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, try changing the 65536 to 1048576 and `Dim counter as Integer` to `Dim counter as Long`, I didn't realize you had so many rows